# Public static readonly objects c#

Tags: c#, oop

Is there any disadvantage to using public static read-only objects in a web application? I have not used them before.

I have a web application that needs to change the display on the page depending on the user's permissions and the state of their existing action.

This is the static class which returns the custom object for their abilities.

```
public static class Abilities
{
   public static readonly Ability ViewPage = new Ability()
   {
       LinkText = "something",
       Hidden = false,
       //Any other additional unchanging properties
   }
}
```

Then for each user when they log in there is a method that sets the abilities that they should have

```
public class User
{
    public List<Ability> GetMyAbilities()
    {
       var myAbilities = new List<Ability>();
       if //some programming logic here
       myAbilities.Add(Abilities.ViewPage);
       return myAbilities;
    }
}
```

This seems to be working as expected, but I wonder if there were any disadvantages or problems when using this method for multiple users?

As per comments - to add a bit of detail. The user class is created for each user when they log in to the web application. The list of abilities refers to stuff that they can do when they have logged in. Each user will therefore get a list of the abilities that they have when they log in to the Default page.

Comment: How do you intent to use them? Only then we can tell you what the disadvantages are.

Comment: You may be reinventing the wheel here - there are already plenty of authorization managers out there (e.g. AzMan.NET). I would suggest using one of these.

Comment: Statics are per app domain and IIS (at least) can recycle app domains at will so you may constantly keep losing and re-initialising static members.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to use immutable objects as `static readonly` too.

Comment: I'm torn between a recommendation. On one hand I avoid static and favor DI/IoC; on the other hand this is arguably showing the value used as a domain object. However, one thing that does bug me is the value is directly associated with UI aspects such as the link text, which does not feel very appropriate.